# Closed continuous surjective function that Is not open

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $f:[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbf{S}^1$ defined as $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$ is closed, surjective, and continuous but not open. I already prooved that it is surjective but I still can't show that it is closed and not open.

Comment: Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology on $[0, 2\pi]$ is very nearly the same as the one on $\mathbf{S}^1$; only the endpoints $0, 2\pi$ are cause problems.
In particular, sets of the form $[0, x)$ or $(x, 2\pi]$ are open in $[0, 2\pi]$, but their image is not open in $\mathbf{S}^1$.

On the other hand, closed sets in the two spaces are exactly the same, which causes $f$ to be a closed map.
To show this formally, you can show that for any closed set $C \subseteq [0, 2\pi]$, $f(C)$ is closed by taking a sequence $\{y_n\} \in f(C)$ converging to a $y_0 \in \mathbf{S}^1$ and arguing from the fact that $C$ is closed and $f$ is continuous that there is a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x_0\in C$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$ and  $f(x_0) = y_0$ so that $y_0 \in F(C)$.

If $y_0 \in \mathbf{S}^2 \setminus\{(1, 0)\}$, there is a unique $x_0 \in C$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$, so this should not give you trouble.
If $y_0 = (0, 1)$, then $f(0) = f(2\pi) = y_0$, and you will need to chose which of these shoud be your $x_0$ for the argument to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The set $[0,\pi)$ is open in $[0,2\pi]$ since it can be written as $(-\pi,\pi)\cap[0,2\pi)$

On the other hand, $f([0,pi))$ is the upper half of the circle including $p=(1,0)$ included which is not open since you cannot have an open set $U$ on $S^1$ such that
$$p\in U \subseteq f([0,\pi))$$

You can also show that $f([0,\pi))$ is not open by showing its complement is not closed. $p$ is a limit point of $S^1\setminus f([0,\pi))$ and not contained in it.