# Proof of closure criteria and open & closed mapping in $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

## Question

Define $\phi:\mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}^3$ as $\phi(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,xy+yz+xz,xyz)$.

Show that

1. $\phi$ is surjective
2. A subset $Z$ of $\mathbb{C}^3$ is closed iff $\phi^{-1}(Z)$ is closed
3. $\phi$ is an open mapping and a closed mapping

## My attempt

The way the mapping looks reminded me of Vieta's formulae so for the first question I think you can show that for some element $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}$ its preimage is determined by the roots of the cubic polynomial $X^3-aX^2+bX-c$. This gives you $3!$ potential preimages so its evidentally non an injective.

For Part 2 the only idea I have is to employ a direct proof, i.e, suppose $Z \subset \mathbb{C}$ is closed we know that all convergent sequences in $Z$ converge to an element in $Z$. But now $\phi^{-1}(Z)$ is comprised of the set of roots of polynomials as defined above for each element of $Z$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

This seems very tedious to do (this was a question from an admissions test so I think there should be a slicker way to prove it).

I am quite puzzled with how to proceed for the second and third questions. I think maybe the open mapping theorem could be used if its possible to show that $\phi$ is continuous then as we've shown its surjective that should be enough to determine open mapping.

Edit:The questioned linked on this post answers the 3rd question about open/closed mapping. But the second question abt a subset being closed off preimage under $\phi$ is closed is still unanswered.

Comment: Continuous and surjective does not imply being an open map for a generic function, that version of the open mapping theorem only works for linear maps, which $\phi$ is not (see here for a counterexample: [Closed continuous surjective function that Is not open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4550913)). I don't know enough in the theory of several complex variables to know whether you can apply a holomorphic open mapping theorem here though.

Comment: Thanks Bruno that question does answer part 3 but not the second one about the criteria for closure of the subsets. Is there some simple observation that leads to question 2s solution as well?

Comment: It seems like the argument "$\phi$ is a quotient map" from Kritiker's answer gives part $2$: see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map) and [here at the end of the paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties). I do not know myself the proofs related to these quotient maps though, but hopefully that helps.